# My canvas in react native is unuseably laggy for no apparent reason

Tags: react-native, canvas

I'm having a problem where I can't seem make my canvas (meant to take the user-pan as its arguments and make a line based off of that) just draw my lines and dots fluidly.
Im using the react-native-canvas package and as far as I know there is nothing further I can optimize. By themselves, the dots and lines are mostly fine, I can optimize those in different ways, but even if my stroke is quite small it still lags atrociously.
Heres all my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";
import Canvas from "react-native-canvas";
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";
import {
  GestureDetector,
  Gesture,
  GestureHandlerRootView,
} from "react-native-gesture-handler";

const DrawingApp = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const canvas = canvasRef.current;

  const [points, setPoints] = useState([{ x: 0, y: 0 }]);

  const panGesture = Gesture.Pan()
    .onBegin((e) => {
      const startingPoint = { x: e.absoluteX, y: e.absoluteY };
      setPoints([startingPoint]);
  
      canvas.width = Dimensions.get("window").width;
      canvas.height = Dimensions.get("window").height;

      // console.log("UPDATE:", points);
    })
    .onUpdate((e) => {
      if (
        arePositionsTooClose(points[points.length - 1], {
          x: e.absoluteX,
          y: e.absoluteY,
        })
      ) {
        return;
      } else {
        const newPointToAdd = { x: e.absoluteX, y: e.absoluteY };
        setPoints([...points, newPointToAdd]);

        rerenderCanvas();
      }

      // console.log("size", canvasRef.current.width, canvasRef.current.height);
    })
    .onEnd((e) => {
      const endPoint = { x: e.absoluteX, y: e.absoluteY };
      setPoints([...points, endPoint]);
      // rerenderCanvas();
      // console.log("END:", points);
    });

  const rerenderCanvas = async () => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
    // canvas.width = Dimensions.get("window").width;
    // canvas.height = Dimensions.get("window").height;

    const latestPoint = points[points.length - 1];
    const previousPoint = points[points.length - 2];
    // console.log("latestPoint", latestPoint, " ||| previousPoint", previousPoint);

    ///DRAW THE POINTS
    canvasContext.beginPath();
    canvasContext.arc(latestPoint.x, latestPoint.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    canvasContext.fillStyle = "black";
    canvasContext.fill();

    ///DRAW THE LINES BETWEEN THE POINTS
    if (previousPoint) {
      canvasContext.beginPath();
      canvasContext.moveTo(previousPoint.x, previousPoint.y);
      canvasContext.lineTo(latestPoint.x, latestPoint.y);
      canvasContext.strokeStyle = "black";
      canvasContext.lineWidth = 20;
      canvasContext.stroke();
    }
  };

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView>
      <View className="w-[100%] h-[100%] bg-black">
        <GestureDetector gesture={panGesture}>
          <View>
          <Canvas
            ref={canvasRef}
            className="w-[100%] h-[100%] bg-white top-0 right-0 left-0"
            // onLayout={() => {
            //   const canvas = canvasRef.current;
            //   const windowWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
            //   const windowHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
            //   canvas.width = windowWidth;
            //   canvas.height = windowHeight;
            // }}
          />
          <Canvas
            ref={canvasRef}
            className="w-[100%] h-[100%] bg-slate-300 top-0 right-0 left-0 absolute bg-transparent"
            onLayout={() => {
              const canvas = canvasRef.current;
              const windowWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
              const windowHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
              canvas.width = windowWidth;
              canvas.height = windowHeight;
            }}
          />
          </View>
        </GestureDetector>
      </View>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
};

const arePositionsTooClose = (position1, position2) => {
  const distance = Math.sqrt(
    Math.pow(position2.x - position1.x, 2) +
      Math.pow(position2.y - position1.y, 2)
  );
  return distance < 20;
};

export default DrawingApp;
```

Thanks for any potential help, I'm extremely lost here so any suggestions would be really appreciated, even if they are just thoughts.